# trigger "continue" button in tel field using tablets/mobile phones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, tablet

Using pads/tablets or mobile phones only (please open both links with your tablet/mobile phone):

I can trigger in a text field if a user presses enter like here:

```
jsfiddle.net/Bhf5a/
```

Does anyone know how I submit the form when the field is specified as "tel" (user friendly keyboard opens) and the users clicks "finished" or "continue" etc.

```
jsfiddle.net/Bhf5a/106/
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit the input box by enter key event, the input element must be inside the form element as below

```
<form action="index.php">
</form>
```

Otherwise you can get all the input element values through script and you can do the ajax post.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work at all. Still the same.

Comment: You have to change the button type to 'Submit' as here <input type="Submit" value="Login" name="loginBtn" id="loginBtn">

Comment: OK! Got it. Thanks a ton!!